# How can I share a USB printer on MacOS

Tags: macos, usb, printing, sharing

I have a Brother DCP-7040 USB connected printer on my High Sierra system that I'd like to share on my network if possible. It is using the Brother-supplied CUPS driver, which I just updated yesterday. The driver version shows up as "4.5.2" in the printer's "General" settings.

In **Printers and Scanners Preferences** I have the box checked beside "Share this printer on the network". In **Sharing Preferences** I have the boxes checked beside "Printer Sharing" and beside the specific printer, and I have "Everyone Can Print" in the "Users" box.

I have two other Macs on my network. Neither of them can see this supposedly shared printer.

I'm pretty sure I had this working under either El Capitan or Yosemite, though at that time I had a Win10 system on the network and no other Macs.

Comment: Are the other two Macs also connected to the same network that the first Mac is using to *share* the printer?

Comment: can you share anything (like screen) with other Mac's

Comment: Do you have the firewall turned on?  If so, turn it off to see if Printer Sharing starts working

Comment: All three Macs are connected to the same network.
Screen sharing works fine.
I'll update this comment when I have a chance to check on the firewall.
Perhaps I should also turn off Little Snitch (running only on the Mac to which the USB printer is connected directly)...

Comment: Little Snitch is most likely your problem.  Most people do not need it.

Comment: Disabling Little Snitch didn’t help. (I have, however, left it disabled for several weeks now.)

Answer (score 1):

After Printer Sharing is enabled, follow these steps to connect to that printer from other computers on your network:

- Click System Preferences in the Dock.
- Click the Print & Fax icon.
- Click the Add button (which carries a plus sign).
- You might be prompted to add a printer automatically when the Printer Setup Utility opens. Click the Add button to begin the addition.
- From the Browser window that opens, click the Default button on the toolbar.
- Choose the printer.
- Click the shared printer you want to use and then click the Add button.

Comment: This is actually just what I did when I set up the printer on the serving Mac.
I've deleted it and added it back a couple of times too.